# Get file paths for files in Centennial app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, desktop-bridge

When converting an app to a Windows Store app, we add the files as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion). But now - how do we access them? What's their path?

They're not in the special folder created for the package.

Comment: Which files specifically? Are these files a part of your app which you want to open - let's say a text file for reading?

Comment: @PrashantHPhadke-MSFT image files which I need to load to a Bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder structure in your project where you can include the files and then since you are already crossing the Centennial Bridge, you can start using the Windows.Storage.StorageFile WinRT API to interact with files.

For example, you can use: StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///folderUnderYourAppRoot/image.bmp")); to get the file which is under the "folderUnderYourAppRoot". This is the generic guidance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files, so you can review it further...

Comment: Thanks. (Though I would still like a conventional way of finding it if that's possible.)

Comment: Did you try the Win32 equivalent of CreateFile with the relative path?

Comment: Yes. It gets `C:\Windows\system32\folderName`. (I'm using `new DirectoryInfo(folderName)`).

Comment: See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes

Comment: I don't see anything there about how to access files that come with the app. It's talking mainly about appdata and the registry. Or did I miss something?

Comment: From that article...."Reading C:\Windows\System32 returns the contents of C:\Windows\System32 plus the contents of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\package_name\VFS\SystemX86"